# Implementation of a kill word or line function in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I implement a function in emacs that kills a word, then if called again immediately it kills the entire line, perhaps called `kill-word-or-line`. I'm a bit of an elisp n00b but may be able to do it myself if someone could point me to a function that behaves in a similar way i.e. has different actions when called twice in succession.

It would be good if the kill ring contained the full line if the kill line version is called i.e. I guess the killed word would need to be inserted again before the line is killed. Here's an example: ( the'|' indicates the point position)

`This is an exam|ple line.`

; call `kill-word-or-line` the first time to get something like...

`This is an | line.`

; call `kill-word-or-line` again to get...

|

The kill-ring should contain `example` and `This is an example line.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following advice on `kill-region` to either kill the selected region, or kill first the word at point then the entire line.

Kill word or line

```lisp
(defadvice kill-region (before slick-cut-line first activate compile)
  "When called interactively kill the current word or line.

Calling it once without a region will kill the current word.
Calling it a second time will kill the current line."
  (interactive
   (if mark-active (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (if (eq last-command 'kill-region)
        (progn
          ;; Return the previous kill to rebuild the line
          (yank)
          ;; Add a blank kill, otherwise the word gets appended.
          ;; Change to (kill-new "" t) to remove the word and only
          ;; keep the whole line.
          (kill-new "")
          (message "Killed Line")
          (list (line-beginning-position)
                (line-beginning-position 2)))
      (save-excursion
        (forward-char)
        (backward-word)
        (mark-word)
        (message "Killed Word")
        (list (mark) (point)))))))
```

This does the same, but copying rather than killing.

Copy word or line

```lisp
(defadvice kill-ring-save (before slick-copy-line activate compile)
  "When called interactively with no region, copy the word or line

Calling it once without a region will copy the current word.
Calling it a second time will copy the current line."
    (interactive
     (if mark-active (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
       (if (eq last-command 'kill-ring-save)
           (progn
             ;; Uncomment to only keep the line in the kill ring
             ;; (kill-new "" t)
             (message "Copied line")
             (list (line-beginning-position)
                   (line-beginning-position 2)))
         (save-excursion
           (forward-char)
           (backward-word)
           (mark-word)
           (message "Copied word")
           (list (mark) (point)))))))
```

Both are adapted from the commands in [this blog post](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/11/copying-lines-without-selecting-them.html).

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! I just made the messages more consistent, i.e. added "Killed word" and "Killed line messages"

Answer (score 4):

The `last-command` variable contains the last command executed interactively, which you can use to test whether the same command is called twice successively:

```
(defun kill-word-or-line ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq last-command 'kill-word-or-line)
      (message "kill line")
    (message "kill word")))
```

This mechanism is used for example in the implementation of [`undo`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/simple.el?h=emacs-24#n1872)